# Does spring-data by default always use the same persistence context within the same request?

Tags: spring, jpa, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

An example is if my spring controller has two Autowired services, and both services have a PersistenceContext also controled by spring (and i'm doing nothing more), will both share the same context in every request by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will use different ones. A persistence context (`EntityManager`) is defined to be a thread-bound concept in JPA. Thus each request will see a fresh instance of `EntityManager` for each new request.

For a singleton Spring component that gets an `EntityManager` injected, Spring will autowire you a proxy instance so that it can easily exchange the backing instance. This a core Spring container feature and doesn't need anything in Spring Data JPA (see the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-jpa-dao)).